# Downloading a LinkedIn Users CV using the LinkedIn REST Profile API

Tags: php, api

I am wondering if it is possible to make a call to the `LinkedIn` API using `PHP` that will allow me to GET the users uploaded CV.

Currently I'm working on some basic `API` calls that have enabled me to gather information relating to the users contact details, personal details, experience and all of the other fields in their profile. I just cannot seem to find anything within the Developers Docs that talk about retrieving the likes of  a CV if it has been uploaded to their account.

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

I'm wondering if any one has any experience doing something similar? Or if it is even feasible! Of course one possible solution would be to utilize the information I can retrieve from LinkedIn to construct a CV but Ideally I'd prefer to retrieve the document.

My hopes is to create an "Apply Now" button that would pre-populate the application form with user information from LinkedIn. When they click "Apply" It is then emailed to my company HR dept.

An overview of my **Basic** Attempt at utilizing the API: *having trouble copying my code into the editor here. Will attempt to do so later. For now here is my steps.

1. Attempt to authenticate my application as follows:

   ```
   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=<?php echo $api_key ?>&state=<?php echo $state ?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo $redirect_uri ?>">Apply Now</a>
   ```
2. Redirect User to Redirect URL and request an `Access Token` which I then use to make   my API Calls.

I just cant figure out how I might get their CV in whatever format it was uploaded to their LinkedIn Profile.

Comment: Because In that question I was asking about retrieving an `Access Token`. and  You will notice when you read this question that I've since acquired an access token and I'm having difficulty retrieving the users CV...rather than asking an open question on whether this is possible on `SO` I decided I'd do it here. So they are quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users dont upload CV to linkedIn. They fill in their profile. What you should be doing, is, after you get the access token, get the user's profile, and fill in your form with relevant fields.

This can be helpful: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#fullprofile

You would need `r_fullprofile` permission.

If you dont need the full profile of the user, see this. https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile

Comment: In other words, you want to say that it is not possible to retrieve a resume in PDF format from LinkedIn?

Comment: This is not possible anymore. Though they didn't announce it on the [developer news site](https://developer.linkedin.com/) or [their blog](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog), full profile [is not accessible anymore through the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api-v1-migration).